# Как запустить приложение из GUI с правами root&

Tags: linux, bash

Установил zenmap. Через терминал всё работает прекрасно, но во время установки на рабочем столе (в избранном) появился ярлык "Zenmap (as root)". По клику ничего не происходит, ну потому, я не под root. Сообственно, хочу понять, а как такие ярлыки использовать? Как в GUI переключаются на root пользователя? Или может быть не надо переключаться, а можно из-под юзера как-то запустить такой ярлык? Речь именно про ярлык на рабочем столе, не про терминал.

Answer (score 3):

Создай файл ~/.local/bin/zenmap

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $UID -ne 0 ]]; then
    pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY $0 $@
    exit $?
fi

/путь/к/zenmap
```

Сделай его исполняемым.

Создай ярлык в меню ~/.local/share/applications/zenmap.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Zenmap policykit
Exec=/home/user/.local/bin/zenmap
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;
Icon=/usr/share/zenmap/pixmaps/zenmap.png
```

ПС. В поставке пакета ubuntu 18.04 ярлык уже создан.

Ничего не происходит потому что не хватает gksu или gksudo. Посмотрите файл /usr/share/applications/zenmap-root.desktop блокнотом - посмотрите чего именно.